# System of polynomial equations with Solve does not converge

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

The Exp-method [1] is an analytical solution method for differential equations. Essentially, the method boils down to the solution of a system 
of nonlinear polynomial algebraic equations. In [1] (and in many other related papers) it is always said that the algebraic equations are solved using
Mathematica (or Maple or Matlab). However, when I try to solve these equations, Mathematica keeps running forever and does not seem to converge. What is going wrong?

Here is the list of equations:

```
 listofeqs = {b2 (-a2 b0 + a0 b2) (a2 + b2 c E^d - a2 E^(2 d)) == 0, 
    a2^2 (-1 + E^(2 d)) (b0^2 E^d + b1 b2 (1 + E^(2 d))) + 
    b2^2 E^d (2 a1 b2 c E^d - a0^2 (-1 + E^(2 d)) + 
    a0 b0 c (1 + E^(2 d))) == 
    a2 b2 (a1 b2 (-1 + E^(4 d)) + 
    c E^d (2 b1 b2 E^d + b0^2 (1 + E^(2 d)))), 
    a2^2 b0 b1 (-1 - E^d + E^(3 d) + E^(4 d)) == 
    a2 (a1 b0 b2 (-1 + E^(4 d)) - 
    a0 (-1 + E^(2 d)) (b0^2 E^d + b1 b2 (1 + E^(2 d))) + 
    b0 c (b0^2 E^(2 d) + 
    b1 b2 (1 + 2 E^d + 2 E^(3 d) + E^(4 d)))) + 
    b2 (a0^2 b0 E^d (-1 + E^(2 d)) - 
    a1 b0 b2 c E^d (2 + E^d + 2 E^(2 d)) + 
    a0 (a1 b2 (-1 - E^d + E^(3 d) + E^(4 d)) - 
    c (b0^2 E^(2 d) + b1 b2 (1 - E^(2 d) + E^(4 d))))), (a2 b1 -
    a1 b2) (-a1 b2 - 2 b1 b2 c - b0^2 c E^d - 2 b0^2 c E^(2 d) - 
    b0^2 c E^(3 d) + a1 b2 E^(4 d) - 2 b1 b2 c E^(4 d) + 
    a0 b0 (-1 + E^d) (1 + E^d)^3 + a2 b1 (-1 + E^(4 d))) == 0, 
    a1^2 b0 b2 (-1 - E^d + E^(3 d) + E^(4 d)) == 
    a1 (a2 b0 b1 (-1 + E^(4 d)) - 
    a0 (-1 + E^(2 d)) (b0^2 E^d + b1 b2 (1 + E^(2 d))) + 
    b0 c (b0^2 E^(2 d) + 
    b1 b2 (1 + 2 E^d + 2 E^(3 d) + E^(4 d)))) + 
    b1 (a0^2 b0 E^d (-1 + E^(2 d)) - 
    a2 b0 b1 c E^d (2 + E^d + 2 E^(2 d)) + 
    a0 (a2 b1 (-1 - E^d + E^(3 d) + E^(4 d)) - 
    c (b0^2 E^(2 d) + b1 b2 (1 - E^(2 d) + E^(4 d))))), 
    a1^2 (-1 + E^(2 d)) (b0^2 E^d + b1 b2 (1 + E^(2 d))) + 
    b1^2 E^d (2 a2 b1 c E^d - a0^2 (-1 + E^(2 d)) + 
    a0 b0 c (1 + E^(2 d))) == 
    a1 b1 (a2 b1 (-1 + E^(4 d)) + 
    c E^d (2 b1 b2 E^d + b0^2 (1 + E^(2 d)))), 
    b1 (-a1 b0 + a0 b1) (a1 + b1 c E^d - a1 E^(2 d)) == 0}
```

I try to solve these equations with

```
Solve[listofeqs, {a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2}, Reals]
```

but no convergence is achieved. What is going wrong? In the paper they solve exactly these equations.

[1] A. Bekir, "Application of the Exp-function method for nonlinear differential-difference equations," Appl. Math. Comput., vol. 215, no. 11, pp. 4049-4053, 2010.

Comment: What is `c` and `d`? Also consider `NSolve`, you are trying to compute an exact answer, is that needed?

Comment: There are other variables in that system of equations and moreover it is not a system of polynomial equations. Might want to try `FindRoot`.

Comment: I only want to solve for the variables a0,a1,a2,b0,b1,b2, whereas the values of c and d are fixed. Hence, it is a polynomial equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although these equations cannot be solved in a reasonable amount of time by a single application of `Solve` or `Reduce`, the can be solved.  Begin by solving the first and last equations for `{b1, b2}`.

```
sb12 = Solve[Extract[listofeqs, {{1}, {7}}], {b1, b2}] // FullSimplify
(* {{b1 -> 0, b2 -> 0}, {b1 -> 0, b2 -> (a2 b0)/a0}, {b1 -> 0, b2 -> (2 a2 Sinh[d])/c}, 
    {b1 -> (a1 b0)/a0, b2 -> 0}, {b1 -> (a1 b0)/a0, b2 -> (a2 b0)/a0}, 
    {b1 -> (a1 b0)/a0, b2 -> (2 a2 Sinh[d])/c}, 
    {b1 -> (2 a1 Sinh[d])/c, b2 -> (2 a2 Sinh[d])/c}, {b1 -> (2 a1 Sinh[d])/c, b2 -> 0}, 
    {b1 -> (2 a1 Sinh[d])/c, b2 -> (a2 b0)/a0}} *)
```

Then, each of these nine partial solutions can be substituted into the remaining five equations, which then can be solved.  For instance,

```
Solve[listofeqs /. sb12[[1]], {a0, a1, a2, b0}]
(* {{b0 -> 0}, {a1 -> 0, a2 -> 0}} *)
```

with the remaining variables undetermined.  However, `Solve` also return the warning,

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

Use `Reduce` to see what was missed, if desired.

```
Reduce[listofeqs /. sb12[[1]], {a0, a1, a2, b0}]
(* (a1 == 0 && a2 == 0) || (E^d == -1 && c != 0 && b0 == (a0 - a0 E^(2 d))/c) || 
   (E^d == 1 && c != 0 && b0 == (a0 (-1 + E^(2 d)))/c) || 
   (E^(2 d) == 1 && E^d == -1 && c == 0) || (E^(2 d) == 1 && E^d == 1 && c == 0) || 
   (E^d == -1 && c == 0 && -1 + E^(2 d) != 0 && a0 == 0) || 
   (E^d == 1 && c == 0 && -1 + E^(2 d) != 0 && a0 == 0) || b0 == 0 || E^d == 0 *)
```

Thus, the solutions missed by `Solve` are valid only for special values of `c` and `d`.  Elements `{2, 3, 4, 8}` of `sb12` yield similar results.

```
(* {{a1 -> 0}, {b0 -> 0}} *)
(* {{a0 -> 1/2 b0 c Csch[d], a1 -> 0}, {a1 -> 0, a2 -> 0}, {a2 -> 0, b0 -> 0}, 
    {a0 -> 0, a1 -> 0, b0 -> 0}} *)
(* {{a2 -> 0}, {b0 -> 0}} *)
(* {{a0 -> 1/2 b0 c Csch[d], a2 -> 0}, {a1 -> 0, a2 -> 0}, {a1 -> 0, b0 -> 0}, 
    {a0 -> 0, a2 -> 0, b0 -> 0}} *)
```

Element `7` yields more complicated expressions,

```
(* {{b0 -> (2 a0 Sinh[d])/c}, {a0 -> 1/2 b0 c (-1 + 2 Cosh[d]) Csch[d], 
     a2 -> (b0^2 c^2 Csch[d]^4 Sinh[d/2]^2)/(4 a1)}, 
    {a1 -> 0, a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 0, b0 -> 0}} *)
```

and element `5` yields an empty set.  Elements `{6, 9}` require a bit more work.

```
FullSimplify[listofeqs[[2 ;; 6]] /. sb12[[9]]]
```

although too lengthy to be reproduced here, is found to have a common factor, `b0 c - 2 a0 Sinh[d]` Hence, a solution for element `6` is

```
b0 -> 2 a0 Sinh[d]/c
```

with the other variables undetermined.  There are no other solutions for element `6` except those already identified above.  Element `9` yields the same results.

Thus, `listofeqs` has many solutions, none of which determine all six variables.

Comment: that is the answer I was looking for.